# Tar.gz files are not extarcting in Google cloud bucket using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload tar.gz files into google cloud bucket using jmeter. Here i am using File management service, GCS & Jmeter.

Execution flow.
1. Using get Request i am hitting FMS.In response I'll get response message. this response contains the URL to upload the file to GCS.
2. Now the file SJ311.tar.gz file is uploaded in the folder iviu/SJ311 folder in GCS.
3. In GCS cloud function is written a code which will extract the .gz file & all .csv files should be extracted successfully.

Issue : through POSTMAN i am able to do this i.e. file is uploaded & it is decompressing the tar file but using jmeter file is uploaded successfully but its not extracting/decompressing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution to the above question is, under File upload section-> under Parameter name field i added DOM attribute or webelement value for the "upload file" button which is present in Google cloud storage screen.

Now after removing that parameter value, file is getting uploaded successfully.

[image]

If we add the attribute value, file will get uploaded successfully but it will be corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to send the request using Postman and see that JMeter behaves differently than it means that you're not sending the same request using JMeter.

Most probably this is due to missing or incorrectly defined [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) so make sure to compare each and every detail of the request and given you send the same requests you should get the same behaviour/response.

Going forward if something is working in Postman and not working in JMeter you can just record the relevant request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), just [configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008893713-How-do-I-configure-Postman-to-work-through-a-proxy-) and run your request, JMeter will capture it and properly build the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), etc.

Just remember to [copy the file(s) you will be uploading to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter/) prior to recording, otherwise JMeter will not be able to capture the request.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your suggestion.I found the solution & its working.